# PHP loads not wanted elements from a XML file

Tags: php, xml, nodes

I wan't to load some data from my XML file using this function:

```
public function getElements()
{
    $elements = array();

    $element = $this->documentElement->getElementsByTagName('elements')->item(0);

    // checks if it has any immunities
    if( isset($element) )
    {
        // read all immunities
        foreach( $element->getElementsByTagName('element') as $v)
        {
            $v = $v->attributes->item(0);

            // checks if immunity is set
            if($v->nodeValue > 0)
            {
                $elements[$v->nodeName] = $v->nodeValue;
            }
        }
    }

    return $elements;
}
```

I wan't to load that elements from my XML file:

```
<elements>
    <element physicalPercent="10"/>
    <element icePercent="10"/>
    <element holyPercent="-10"/>
</elements>
```

I wan't to load only element node name and node value.

Got this code in my query loop:

```
            $elements = $monster->getElements();
            $elN = 0;
            $elC = count($elements);
            if(!empty($elements)) {
                foreach($elements as $element => $value) {
                    $elN++;
                    $elements_string .= $element . ":".$value;
                    if($elC != $elN)
                        $elements_string .= ", ";
                }
            }
```

And finally - the output of $elements_string variable is wrong:

```
earthPercent:50, holyPercent:50, firePercent:15, energyPercent:5, physicalPercent:25, icePercent:30, deathPercent:30firePercent:20, earthPercent:75firePercent:20, earthPercent:75firePercent:20, earthPercent:75physicalPercent:70, holyPercent:20, deathPerce
```

It **should** rather return:

> ```
> physicalPercent:10, icePercent:10, holyPercent:-10
> ```

Could you help me one more time?:)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add the code to your question that is actually important: How/Where do you call that function? What is the actual data you pass into that function? The code only does what you coded there-in but you're not showing the whole data you're passing to that function. Please reduce the code posted with your question to the minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the XML-Parser doesn't magically know which elements you want to load and which you won't - you have to filter this by yourself. Then you have to decide where you want to filter your desired elements in the `getElements`-function you posted or in your "query loop" as you call it.

Should the `getElements` be some kind of general function which **must** return all elements? Then you should change that check `if($v->nodeValue > 0)` to something like `if(!empty($v->nodeValue))` otherwise you wont get the "holyPercent" value since this is negative (and the old expression becomes false).

Then in your "query loop", just select your desired elements:

```php
foreach($elements as $element => $value) {
    if(in_array($element, array("physicalPercent", "icePercent", "holyPercent"))) {
        $elN++;
        $elements_string .= $element . ":".$value;
        if($elC != $elN)
            $elements_string .= ", ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlfile);
```

And then:

```
for($i=1;$i<Count($xml->elements);$i++)
    echo $xml->elements[$i][0];
```

Didn't try if it works with [0], usually i use :

```
    echo $xml->elements[$i]['attributename'];
```

Comment: I know that. The problem is that the attributes I wan't to insert into $elements_string variable should be for each data, now it just counts to itself the data of every loop.